# Python Bluetooth socket(s) for sending and receiving simultaneously

Tags: python, sockets, bluetooth

Using pyBluez, I use the following code to advertise and listen for a bluetooth connection:

```
def connect_socket():
    global client_sock

    try:

        server_sock = BluetoothSocket(RFCOMM)
        server_sock.bind(("", PORT_ANY))
        server_sock.listen(1)

        port = server_sock.getsockname()[1]

        uuid = "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"

        advertise_service(server_sock, "GSA",
                          service_id=uuid,
                          service_classes=[uuid, SERIAL_PORT_CLASS],
                          profiles=[SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE])

        print("Waiting for connection on RFCOMM channel %d" % port)

        client_sock, client_info = server_sock.accept()

        print("Accepted connection from ", client_info)

    except Exception as e: (yes, I know I'm catching all exceptions)
        print(e)
```

I use the following to call the above and send data out from the socket. (I wind up waiting for a connection on every possible channel, which is not desirable, but that's not my only problem or the one that's prompting this question, though I'd like to fix it, too.)

```
def write_bt(message):

    global client_sock

    if client_sock is None:
        threading.Thread(target=connect_socket).start()

    if client_sock is not None:
        try:
            client_sock.send(message)
        except Exception as e:
            gsa_msg.message(e)
            client_sock = None
```

I also need to receive data from the socket and write it to a usb connection. For this, I use the following:

```
def forward_bt_to_usb():

    global client_sock
    global serUSB

    if (client_sock is not None) and (serUSB is not None):
        try:
            data = client_sock.recv(1024)
            serUSB.write(data)
        except Exception as e:
            gsa_msg.error(e)
            client_sock = None
```

Both `write_bt()` and `forward_bt_to_usb()` get called continuously from a loop and are communicating with the same client, but there isn't always data being received over the socket, and `forward_bt_to_usb()` seems to block everything in that case.

I believe that I probably have all of this structured improperly for what I'm trying to do, or perhaps I just need to have separate threads for sending and receiving data, but it's not obvious to me how to do that (Initially I just put some of the code from `forward_bt_to_usb()` in a separate thread, without realizing that that would just keep creating new threads as `forward_bt_to_usb()` kept getting called.)

It seems that what I'm trying to do should be pretty straightforward and certainly not novel, but I haven't been able to find examples or an explanation that I've been able to implement.